# ASP.NET MVC 4 BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing new site in .net mvc 4. I have searched in the internet about my problem, but i didn't find a proper soluation. I am using form in my code - @using(Html.BeginForm()). Every time that i click enter(in a textbox) or i click on a button(regular button), the form is submitted. How can i disable it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to disable it. For example with jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('form').submit(function() {
            // returning false from the submit handler of a form will simply
            // disable it from being submitted to the server
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively you could directly disable it in the form when rendering it:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return false;" }))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: And how i will submit it eventually?

Comment: The same way you disabled it: with javascript. For example you could use an AJAX request or simply call the `.submit()` method on the underlying DOM element.

Comment: sorry but i dont understand you. I have createed jQuery function as you said. And a button that call jQuery function that return true.

Comment: If you return `true` the form will submit. You need to return `false` as shown in my answer if you want to prevent it from submitting. And when you are ready to submit it you could use the `$.ajax` function.